# NoMethodError with Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The user is presented with a contact page where he can add a new contact
by clicking the create button (Then the app takes him in a new page to add the contact's title)

```
<%= link_to "Create", new_contact_path  %>
```

When I click create I get the following error:

```
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0xsomeHEX>:0xsomeHEX>
```

The above error disappears when I create the controller like this:

```
rails generate controller contacts
```

Also the routes.rb file points to:

```
resources :contact
```

Below are my files:

1. [contact_controller.rb](http://pastebin.com/x6y5upGk)
2. [contact_helper.rb](http://pastebin.com/PyV3DZkG)
3. [_form.html.erb](http://pastebin.com/u8Xd4YmM)

What I want to achieve is to go to the new contacts page by typing **someurl/contact/new** instead of **/contacts/new**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config/routes.rb change your contacts route to this:

```
  resources :contacts, path: "contact"
```

That gives you the ability to hit your routes using 'contact' instead of 'contacts'.

Answer (score 1):

rename routes to `resources :contacts`

Comment: `No route matches [GET] "/contact"`

Comment: maybe you have to write `resoures :about` need more info

Comment: Sorry I meant `/contact`

Comment: If you executed `rails generate controller Contacts` then your controller should look like `class ContactsController < ApplicationController`

Comment: I executed `rails generate controller contact`

Answer (score 0):

Please make these changes

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  ....
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :contacts
```

Your views folder should be `views/contacts`

Comment: As I said in a comment above I executed `rails generate controller contact`. What I want to achieve is to be able to go to the contacts page by typing url/contact instead of url/contacts.